# Is there a way to increase the cascade size in Eevee past 4096 pixels?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, image, lighting

I was wondering if there was any way to increase the cascade texture size for sun lights in Eevee, I see no reason for why there *shouldn't* be, but blender limits you to a maximum of 4096 pixels

Comment: Hi :). There are some hard-coded limits to preserve good Eevee performance. Number of nodes, number of lights and indeed the cascade size. You can ask the developers why they chose this number ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you increase it by some other way in Blender - no. Even when I try setting it to something else via Python, Blender validates and rejects it. The value must be one of the included values. You could make your own Blender build with that new option, of course, but there's no guarantee it'll work.

As to why - no idea. I think in most cases, artists don't need a higher resolution. I don't know your use case or situation. I didn't see any discussions about it on [developer.blender.org](http://developer.blender.org/), but maybe you'll have more luck.